# Cmake generated makefile does not generate binary even though it says it does

Tags: build, cmake

I am trying to build a project with the following file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.3)
project(terminalTest)

set(MainSource "/Users/username/Coding/Major Projects/projectname/Backend")
set(TerminalSource "/Users/username/Coding/Major Projects/projectname/Terminal")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -c")

#Bring the headers, such as Student.h into the project
include_directories(${MainSource} ${TerminalSource})

#Can manually add the sources using the set command as follows:
#set(SOURCES src/mainapp.cpp src/Student.cpp)

#However, the file(GLOB...) allows for wildcard additions:
file(GLOB SOURCES
    ${MainSource}/*.cpp
    ${TerminalSource}/*.cpp
)

add_executable(terminalTest ${SOURCES})
```

Which I use the CMAKE GUI with the following configuration to configure and generate a makefile

[image]

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.17

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:


#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : %,v


# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%


# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%,v


# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : SCCS/s.%


# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : s.%


.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E rm -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = "/Users/username/Coding/Major Projects/projectname/Terminal"

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = "/Users/username/Coding/Major Projects/projectname/Terminal/Build"

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake --regenerate-during-build -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache

.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake cache editor..."
    /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache

.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start "/Users/username/Coding/Major Projects/projectname/Terminal/Build/CMakeFiles" "/Users/username/Coding/Major Projects/projectname/Terminal/Build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks"
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start "/Users/username/Coding/Major Projects/projectname/Terminal/Build/CMakeFiles" 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean

.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named terminalTest

# Build rule for target.
terminalTest: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 terminalTest
.PHONY : terminalTest

# fast build rule for target.
terminalTest/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/build
.PHONY : terminalTest/fast

EngineTester.o: EngineTester.cpp.o

.PHONY : EngineTester.o

# target to build an object file
EngineTester.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/EngineTester.cpp.o
.PHONY : EngineTester.cpp.o

EngineTester.i: EngineTester.cpp.i

.PHONY : EngineTester.i

# target to preprocess a source file
EngineTester.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/EngineTester.cpp.i
.PHONY : EngineTester.cpp.i

EngineTester.s: EngineTester.cpp.s

.PHONY : EngineTester.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
EngineTester.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/EngineTester.cpp.s
.PHONY : EngineTester.cpp.s

Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.o: Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.cpp.o

.PHONY : Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.o

# target to build an object file
Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.cpp.o
.PHONY : Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.cpp.o

Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.i: Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.cpp.i

.PHONY : Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.i

# target to preprocess a source file
Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.cpp.i
.PHONY : Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.cpp.i

Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.s: Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.cpp.s

.PHONY : Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.cpp.s
.PHONY : Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.cpp.s

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... terminalTest"
    @echo "... EngineTester.o"
    @echo "... EngineTester.i"
    @echo "... EngineTester.s"
    @echo "... Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.o"
    @echo "... Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.i"
    @echo "... Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.s"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

What is most confusing to me about this whole thing is that this make file does not appear to create a binary even though it claims to.

```
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable terminalTest
clang: warning: -Wl,-search_paths_first: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/Users/username/Coding/Major_Projects/projectname/Backend/Tweaking.cpp.o: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/EngineTester.cpp.o: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
[100%] Built target terminalTest
```

There is no file I can find generated by running make.

I had to add the -c flag because otherwise I got a BUNCH of undefined symbols from code in the backend folder (perhaps it didnt like that headers in that folder are `.hpp` and folders in the terminal folder are `.h`?)

Can you see at all why this script might not create a binary?

For reference the end goal is to take the engine defined in the Backend folder and test it with a bit of code in the Terminal folder in an executable I can run with gdb/valgrind/gprof.

It is worth noting that if I dont use the "-c" flag I get the following error

```
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable terminalTest
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Engine::deconstruct()", referenced from:
      _main in EngineTester.cpp.o
  "Engine::instance", referenced from:
      Engine::shared() in EngineTester.cpp.o
  "Engine::setCount(int)", referenced from:
      _main in EngineTester.cpp.o
  "Engine::simulate()", referenced from:
      _main in EngineTester.cpp.o
  "Engine::Engine()", referenced from:
      Engine::shared() in EngineTester.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [terminalTest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/terminalTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

`EngineTester.cpp` is in the Terminal folder, and the Engine class definition is in the `Backend/Engine/Engine.hpp`.

Comment: I don't see any `add_executable` or `add_library` calls.

Comment: "Can you see at all why this script might not create a binary?" - The script you show has no `add_executable` calls, so it cannot even produce the line `Linking CXX executable terminalTest`. The warnings suggest you have problems in toolchain settings. And adding `-c` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is definitely not a correct way for resolve toolchain problems. Please, add **more info** about your project and provide more **complete code**.

Comment: Sorry I have no clue why the add_executable line was not included. @Tsyvarev

Comment: The error in the last log is the your **actual problem**: `Undefined symbols ...`. Firstly you may check, that `SOURCES` variable **actually** contains all source files you want to compile. E.g. add `message("SOURCES: ${SOURCES}")` line and check its output in the configuration log (when running `cmake`). If you find that all expected source files are compiled, then show the **source file** which **defines** the "Undefined symbols": `deconstruct`, `setCount` and other methods of `Engine` class.

Comment: "Can you see at all why this script might not create a binary?" - By adding `-c` flag you transform **linking** process into **compilation** one. Obviously, compilation won't create an *executable*, it can only create an *object* file.

Comment: Ok so thanks to @Tsyvarev comment I now have a way to debug what is being added to sources. Is there a similar way to figure out what is being added to headers?

Comment: After looking at what was grabbed as far as sources I noticed that most of the files weren't there. Sure enough after changing the GLOB path I did get better results `file(GLOB SOURCES
 ${MainSource}/**.cpp
 ${TerminalSource}/**.cpp
 ${MainSource}/**/*.cpp
 ${TerminalSource}/**/*.cpp
)` However for some reason the list still does not include some files. For example there is folder Backend/Geometry/Types that has a class circle{.h and .cpp} that IS included in the sources list while TimeFirstStrip.cpp is NOT included in the list. Why does the list include some folder items and not others?

Comment: Probably the name (or extension) of `TimeFirstStrip.cpp` file is actually mistyped, or the file didn't exist at the time when `file(GLOB)` was executed. I would assume that globbing works perfectly in CMake, so the problem is on your side. If you want others to help you, then update the question post to the **actual problem** (and remove all unnecessary information from it).

Comment: According to your answer, you had just a mess with your source files. So it just a **typo**-like questions which are rarely useful for other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to the help in the comments I eventually was able to figure out what I was doing wrong here. Here are some notes

- `message("SOURCES: ${SOURCES}")` is a great thing to add to the CMakeList.txt file so you can debug which sources are actually included.
- `GLOB_RECURSE` instead of `GLOB` allows all subdirectories to be explored. Otherwise it just looks at the current layer.
- It would appear CMake does not care if a file ends in `hpp` or `h`.
- Multiple directories can be included by just putting a space between them
- In this multiple code directories scenario I had to put the CMakeLists.txt and the build/source folders in a separate folder from the Terminal folder. Otherwise you get conflicts with build files. I fix this with GLOB_RECURSE vs GLOB.

So in the end this is my resulting lists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.3)
project(terminalTest)

set(MainSource "/Users/username/Coding/Major Projects/projectname/Backend")
set(TerminalSource "/Users/username/Coding/Major Projects/projectname/Terminal")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) 

include_directories(${MainSource} ${TerminalSource})


file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES
    ${MainSource}/*.cpp
)
file(GLOB SOURCES2
    ${TerminalSource}/*.cpp 
)

add_executable(terminalTest ${SOURCES} ${SOURCES2})
message("SOURCES : ${SOURCES}")
```